# how to set latest date on pandas and datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

so in pandas i want to make into like this

```
import datetime as dt
Latest_Date = dt.datetime(2021,03,26)
```

and it turns error like this

```
Latest_Date = dt.datetime(2021,03,26)
                                    ^
SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers
```

i want to make 2021-03-26 as the latest date on `datetime`

i've tried with this `Latest_Date = dt.datetime(2021,3,26)`

but im not so sure if this will in the right way

Comment: `Latest_Date = dt.datetime(2021,3,26)` is indeed the right way. If you always want the latest date you can also use `dt.datetime.now()`

Comment: it's the right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two solution for this.
You can add `o` after any `0` if the day or month contains `0`.
Or you can just put the month as `3` without any zero's before it.

**First:**

```
import datetime as dt
Latest_Date = dt.datetime(2021,0o3,26)
print(Latest_Date)
```

**Second:**

```
import datetime as dt
Latest_Date = dt.datetime(2021,3,26)
print(Latest_Date
```

You can check both from here: [Link_](https://paiza.io/projects/uRyJAoceTnp8O0rY7UINjg)